# How can i retrieve a data from database and display it in a form using its string?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I would like to know how to display the data I fetch on my database into into a form. Anyway here are my codes:

```
<form action="" method="POST" style="height:350px; ">
<?php  while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
    <label>First name</label>
    <input type="text" contenteditable="true" value="<?php echo $row['fname'];?>" class="fname" name="fname"/>
    <label>Middle name</label>
    <input type="text" contenteditable="true" value="<?php echo $row['mname'];?>" class="mname"name="mname"/>
    <label>Last name</label>
    <input type="text" contenteditable="true" value="<?php echo $row['lname'];?>" class="lname" name="lname"/>
    <label>Gender</label>
    <input type="text" contenteditable="true" value="<?php echo $row['gender'];?>" class="gender" name="gender"/>
    <br><label>Birthdate</label>
    <input type="text" contenteditable="true" value="<?php echo $row['bday'];?>" class="bday" name="bday"/>
    <label>Civil Status</label>
    <input type="text" contenteditable="true" value="<?php echo $row['cstatus'];?>" class="cstatus" name="cstatus"/>
    <label>Citizenship</label>
    <input type="text" contenteditable="true" value="<?php echo $row['cship'];?>" class="cship" name="cship"/>
    <label>Addresss</label>
    <input type="text" contenteditable="true" value="<?php echo $row['address'];?>" class="address" name="address"/>
    <br><label>Contact Number</label>
    <input type="text" contenteditable="true" value="<?php echo $row['cnumber'];?>" class="cnumber" name="cnumber"/>
    <label>E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" contenteditable="true" value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>" class="email" name="email"/>
    <label>Father's name:</label>
    <input type="text" contenteditable="true" value="<?php echo $row['fathername'];?>" class="fathername" name="fathername"/>
    <label>Contact number:</label>
    <input type="text" contenteditable="true" value="<?php echo $row['fcontact'];?>" class="fcontact" name="fcontact"/>
    <label>Mother's name:</label>
    <input type="text" contenteditable="true" value="<?php echo $row['mothername'];?>" class="mothername" name="mothername"/>
    <label>Contact number:</label>
    <input type="text" contenteditable="true" value="<?php echo $row['mcontact'];?>" class="mcontact" name="mcontact"/>
    <label>Guardian's name:</label>
    <input type="text" contenteditable="true" value="<?php echo $row['gname'];?>" class="gname" name="gname"/>
    <br><label>Contact Number:</label>
    <input type="text" contenteditable="true" value="<?php echo $row['gcontact'];?>" class="gcontact" name="gcontact"/>
    <label>Current/Last School Attended:</label>
    <input type="text" contenteditable="true" value="<?php echo $row['lschool'];?>" class="lschool" name="lschool"/>
<?php 
}
?>
```

and this is my output
[image]

What I am trying to do is when I clicked the table row on my page the form should be able to display the info of the clicked row, but when there is a new data on my database it just add up and add up on my form instead of having the clicked row summarize information.

Comment: Can you add the code and query that's generating your current `$result` please?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT fname, mname, lname, gender, bday, cstatus, cship, address, cnumber, email,fathername, fcontact, mothername, mcontact,gname,gcontact,lschool FROM register";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);  @KevinStich not sure if this is what youre looking for. the query and codes are above

Comment: That query is pulling all of the records from register, look to refine it to get only the row you want. [SELECT MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

Comment: do i still need to use php on that? @KevinStich or should i just fix the query?